# Android: How to check which Fragment/Activity called the method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

my case is as follows, I have a **common toolbar** between activities **and** fragments, I have a method **attached** to this toolbar (like a back button) which can be called by all, but however, i want this method to behave differently according to the activity/fragment which called it.So what should my code look like inside this method?

Here is my code

```
 public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
    Intent mainActivity=new Intent(this,main_activity.class);
    mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(mainActivity);
    this.finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use putExtra and getExtra with intent and set different values for different activity in put extra to identify the exact calling activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra in your intent, then check it to know who send it. Something like :

**Activity 1**

```
Intent intent = ...
intent.putExtra("SENDER","activity1");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity receiving the intent**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String sender = intent.getExtras().getString("SENDER");
if(sender=="activity1")
//do
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using reflection:

```
if (getClass() == Activity1.class){
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WHy dont you make 1 common activity with a tool bar and a framelayout and switch fragments like that. It is less code to write. This also reduces code redundancy. Or I don't understand what you are asking?